# How to deploy a Java Swing package with JavaFX embedded

Tags: swing, javafx, executable-jar

I want to use some JavaFX features in a Java Swing environment. I used an Oracle demo program: SimpleSwingBrowser.java where JFXPanel is used. Using Eclipse, everything works fine. The problem arises when I create the runnable jar file because it doesn't run and doesn't report errors. I understand that it depends on whether the JavaFX library is used, but I don't know how to fix the problem to have a complete, executable jar file. Oracle has a tutorial for deploying WebStarts and Applets, but I don't see any information for desktop apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of the Oracle information refers to outdated Java 8 technology.  If you use only JDK 8, those tutorials will still probably work (except the webstart and applet stuff).  For deploying modern JavaFX apps, things are a bit complex.  If you can rely on a preinstalled JRE that includes JavaFX (e.g. the "Full JRE" or "JRE FX" distributions from Azul or BellSoft), and don't try to bundle JavaFX with your app that would work.  Otherwise see the packaging info in the [JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).